# MySQL: Select date plus 6 months if less than now() plus 1 month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a given date:

```
2013-12-20
```

This is an **issue date** of a product where the product expiries in 6 months from the date of issue. The expiration date it is not stored so I want to check from the given issue date if it is expiring in the next month of now().

So my guess would be to add 6 months to the issue date and check now + interval of 1 month if it is expiring?

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE DATE_ADD(`issue_date`,INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
< DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY `issue_date` ASC
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: why use `date_add` on one side of the `<` sign and a simple `+' on the other?

Comment: @Mureinik Probably because I'm not sure what I am doing? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Just trying to understand if that was intentional or not. How about `SELECT * FROM products WHERE DATE_ADD(issue_date, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
<  DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY issue_date ASC` ?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM products
WHERE Now() <= DATE_ADD(issue_date, INTERVAL 7 MONTH)
&& Now() >= DATE_ADD(issue_date, INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
ORDER BY issue_date ASC;`

- The first item that has to be returned has due date today (so issue date + 6 months = today);
- than due date tomorrow (so issue date + 6 months + 1 day = today);
- ...
- than due date one month from today(so issue date + 6 months + 1 month = issue date + 7 months = today)

Comment: please add some explanation of your code, what it does, and how it solves the problem. This will help others who see your answer in the future

Answer (score 0):

here's a suggestions which might help 
$date = date("y-m-d", strtotime(" +6 months"));
this will result in date 6 months later from current date:
similarly,
for one month from current date
$date = date("y-m-d", strtotime(" +1 months"));

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `products` 
WHERE NOW() >= DATE_ADD(`issue_date`,INTERVAL 5 MONTH) 
  AND NOW() <= DATE_ADD(`issue_date`,INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
ORDER BY `issue_date` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query says to select all the products that will expire within a month or had already expired. You could use `between` clause

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE DATE_ADD(`issue_date`,INTERVAL 6 MONTH) between NOW() and  DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY `issue_date` ASC
```

[Between clause in Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the product expiries in 6 months from the date of issue and if it is expiring in the next month, the it is better to add this 1 month to the 6th in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE issue_date <= DATE_ADD(issue_date,INTERVAL 7 MONTH)
ORDER BY issue_date ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM `products` where DATE_ADD(`issue_date`,INTERVAL 6 MONTH) < CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few of these answers I ended up working it out with this:

```
SELECT * FROM  `products` 
WHERE DATE_ADD(  `issue_date` , INTERVAL 6 MONTH ) 
< DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```